# jQuery cssHook - переопределить поведение функции element.css()

Tags: jquery, плагин

В `jQuery` есть возможность создавать [кастомные `css`-свойства](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/).

И, например, есть [`jQuery.transit`](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit), который использует `cssHooks` и я бы хотел добавить в него кое-что.

Я хочу чтобы CSS-стили `left` и `top` работали как `x` и `y` в `jQuery.transit` (где они превращаются в `css`-свойство `transform: translate(x, y)`).

Итак, основываясь на документации и внутреннем `API` `jQuery.transit`, я добавляю свойства `left` и `top` в `jQuery.transit`:

```
registerCssHook('left', true);

/* some code */

setter {
  /* some code */
  left: function(x) {
    this.set('translate', x, null);
  },
  /* some code */
}

/* some code */

getter {
  /* some code */
  left: function() {
    return this._translateX || 0;
  },
  /* some code */
}

/* some code */

function registerCssHook(prop, isPixels) {
  // For certain properties, the 'px' should not be implied.
  if (!isPixels) { $.cssNumber[prop] = true; }

  $.transit.propertyMap[prop] = support.transform;

  $.cssHooks[prop] = {
    get: function(elem) {
      var t = $(elem).css('transit:transform');
      return t.get(prop);
    },

    set: function(elem, value) {
      var t = $(elem).css('transit:transform');
      t.setFromString(prop, value);

      $(elem).css({ 'transit:transform': t });
    }
  };
}
```

И все почти идеально.
Теперь, когда я пишу:

```
$('.class').css('left', '40px');
```

Все элементы с классом `class` получают следующие св-ва:

- `transform: translate(x, y)`
- и.. почему-то `left: x`

Т.е. `cssHook` работает не через **переопределение**, а через **добавление обработчика**.

И да, `jQuery.transit` точно использует `cssHooks`, а не собственную реализацию.

Вопрос: как сделать переопределение?
Как заменить стандартное поведение функции `css()` для `left` и `top` на то, что описано в `cssHooks`?

Comment: Надо поправить код, убрать лишнее. И к гадалке не ходи, даже скролл уберётся

Comment: В коде только то, что относится к делу. Если глянуть на то, как реализовано св-во `x` в jQuery.transit и затем на мой код, можно увидеть, что с моей стороны ошибок нет. + Я привожу часть кода, где подтверждается использование cssHooks, а не внутренней системы.